# Replacing union all with Unpivot in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, union, unpivot

I have a below query:

```sql
SELECT COL1,ABC AS COL2,'1' AS SEQ,'GRP 10' AS GRP_NAME,'ABC' AS INPUT_COL_NAME,'NEW1' AS OUTPUT_COL_NAME FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1,MNO AS COL2,'2' AS SEQ,'GRP 10' AS GRP_NAME,'MNO' AS INPUT_COL_NAME,'NEW2' AS OUTPUT_COL_NAME FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1,XYZ AS COL2,'3' AS SEQ,'GRP 10' AS GRP_NAME,'XYZ' AS INPUT_COL_NAME,'NEW3' AS OUTPUT_COL_NAME FROM TABLE1
```

INPUT TABLE DATA:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE1
```

> | COL1 | ABC | MNO | XYZ |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 20 | 100 |
> | 2 | 15 | 50 | 150 |

OUTPUT IS:

> | COL1 | COL2 | SEQ | GRP_NAME | INPUT_COL_NAME | OUTPUT_COL_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 1 | GRP_NEW | ABC | NEW1 |
> | 2 | 15 | 1 | GRP_NEW | ABC | NEW1 |
> | 1 | 20 | 2 | GRP_NEW | MNO | NEW2 |
> | 2 | 50 | 2 | GRP_NEW | MNO | NEW2 |
> | 1 | 100 | 3 | GRP_NEW | XYZ | NEW3 |
> | 2 | 150 | 3 | GRP_NEW | XYZ | NEW3 |

Can above query be transformed into PIVOT query? to generate same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `UNPIVOT` (rather than `PIVOT`):

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       seq,
       'GRP_NEW' AS grp_name,
       input_col_name,
       output_col_name
FROM   table1
UNPIVOT (
  input_col_name FOR ( col2, seq, output_col_name ) IN (
    abc AS ( 'ABC', 1, 'NEW1' ),
    mno AS ( 'MNO', 2, 'NEW2' ),
    xyz AS ( 'XYZ', 3, 'NEW3' )
  )
)
ORDER BY seq, col1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( COL1, ABC, MNO, XYZ ) AS
SELECT 1,  0, 20, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 15, 50, 150 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 | SEQ | GRP_NAME | INPUT_COL_NAME | OUTPUT_COL_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ABC | 1 | GRP_NEW | 0 | NEW1 |
> | 2 | ABC | 1 | GRP_NEW | 15 | NEW1 |
> | 1 | MNO | 2 | GRP_NEW | 20 | NEW2 |
> | 2 | MNO | 2 | GRP_NEW | 50 | NEW2 |
> | 1 | XYZ | 3 | GRP_NEW | 100 | NEW3 |
> | 2 | XYZ | 3 | GRP_NEW | 150 | NEW3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0afed3464dc015aa6232cef1b37c217a)*